# Squid Transparent issue

Tags: squid

I am facing the issue with transparent squid where I am unable to browse to any HTTP site yahoomail.com is not working while https://mail.yahoo.com is working.

Please see my squid config

```
# Recommended minimum configuration:
#

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt to list your (internal) IP networks from where browsing
# should be allowed

acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/22  # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 192.168.133.0/24       # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src fc00::/7       # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10      # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines

#acl SSL_ports port 443 563 1863 5190 5222 5050 6667
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

#
# Recommended minimum Access Permission configuration:
#
# Deny requests to certain unsafe ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports


# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

# Only allow cachemgr access from localhost
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager

# We strongly recommend the following be uncommented to protect innocent
# web applications running on the proxy server who think the only
# one who can access services on "localhost" is a local user
#http_access deny to_localhost

#
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
#

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt localnet in the ACL section to list your (internal) IP networks
# from where browsing should be allowed
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost

# And finally deny all other access to this proxy
http_access deny all

# Squid normally listens to port 8080

http_port 8080 transparent

# Uncomment and adjust the following to add a disk cache directory.
cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 100 16 256

# Leave coredumps in the first cache dir
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid

#
# Add any of your own refresh_pattern entries above these.
#
refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%      1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%      0
refresh_pattern .               0       20%     4320
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason port 443 is allowed, but port 80 isn't is do to the deny on CONNECT connections to anyport that's not in the SSL_ports acl:

```
# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
```

Connecting through the proxy is doing a CCONNECT.  But you're only allowing CONNECT to ports in the `SSL_ports` acl.  In which you have only `443`.

Try changing it to

```
# Deny CONNECT to other than identified Safe ports
http_access deny CONNECT !Safe_ports
```

And see if that makes a difference.